# Rails Merge Hash & Array with different Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, merge

If I have an array of months like:

```
["05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05"]
```

And a hash of a month value and a month_sum:

```
[{"month"=>5, "month_sum"=>20}, {"month"=>4, "month_sum"=>100}]
```

*How do I merge the hash into the array so I get something like?*

```
[{"05" => 20}, {"07" => 0}, {"08" => 0}, {"09" => 0}, {"10" => 0}, {"11" => 0}, {"12" => 0}, {"01" => 0}, {"02" => 0}, {"03" => 0}, {"04" => 100}, {"05" => 0}, {"06" => 0}]
```

**Edit**

The month array is generated from:

```
date_from  = Date.parse(params[:search][:date_from])
date_to    = Date.parse(params[:search][:date_to])
date_range = date_from..date_to

date_months = date_range.map {|d| Date.new(d.year, d.month, 1) }.uniq
@date_range = date_months.map {|d| d.strftime "%m" }
```

So a caveat is that if the range is over, say a two year period, the array will have duplicate month-values. I suppose I need to add the year into that array?

Is there a better way to do this?

The end goal here is to get a hash or array for highcharts to display monthly sums of fuel usage for particular vehicles. (just so you have some context).

Comment: Programatically, with loops. There is no magic method to do so. What have you tried?

Comment: Question is not clear. 1. What is the rule that tells the first `{"05" ...}` should have `"20"` and not the second one? 2. By what rule is `{"06" ...}` inserted into the expected output? Is there a systematic rule here, or is it just your sloppiness?

Comment: You've also moved a "06" from the 2nd element to the last element, seemingly arbitrarily.

Comment: Sorry, This is just a rough example--so yes, arbitrarily.

Comment: How is this not a real question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Note the final product is a hash, not an array of hashes. But I think a hash is easier to work with in this case.

```
# starting variables
array_of_months = ["05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05"]
month_sums = [{"month"=>5, "month_sum"=>20}, {"month"=>4, "month_sum"=>100}]

# clean up array_of_months
months = array_of_months.compact.sort
=> ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]

# compress month_sums into single key/value pairs such that first value becomes the key and second value becomes the value
sums = month_sums.inject({}) { |a, ms| a.merge!("%02d" % ms['month'] => ms['month_sum']) }
=> { "05" => 20, "04" => 100 }

# generate hash of all months and match sums value if key is present otherwise assign value zero
all_month_sums = months.inject({}) { |h, m| h.merge!(m => sums[m] || 0) }
=> {"01"=>0, "02"=>0, "03"=>0, "04"=>100, "05"=>20, "06"=>0, "07"=>0, "08"=>0, "09"=>0, "10"=>0, "11"=>0, "12"=>0}
```

EDIT (in light of new information)

```
# starting variables
months = ["05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05"]
month_sums = [{"month"=>5, "month_sum"=>20}, {"month"=>4, "month_sum"=>100}, {"month" => 5, "month_sum" => 99 }]

# iterate each month, select the first match, remove the match when done. if no match just give month a zero.
months.inject([]) do |a, month|
  if s = month_sums.select { |s| month.to_i == s['month'] }.first
    a << { "%02d" % s['month'] => s['month_sum'] }
    s['month'] = nil
  else
    a << { month => 0 }
  end
  a
end
=> [{"05"=>20}, {"06"=>0}, {"07"=>0}, {"08"=>0}, {"09"=>0}, {"10"=>0}, {"11"=>0}, {"12"=>0}, {"01"=>0}, {"02"=>0}, {"03"=>0}, {"04"=>100}, {"05"=>99}]
```

Comment: This is good and it works. Per my edit, can you edit to remove the sort?

Comment: Saw your edit. Yeah, this would be a problem if you have duplicate months. And the end product couldn't be an array because the keys have to be unique. Gotta think about this...

Comment: Perhaps I just need to make the date array 'm-yyyy'?